# XWiki + MySQL Database: Errors

Tags: mysql, http, xampp, tomcat7, xwiki

I have (as far as I know) properly followed all of the instructions on xwiki.org, and I have also searched high and low for answers to my errors, but have unfortunately been unable to resolve them by myself.

I have downloaded XWiki in two different formats. The first is the `.exe` installer, and the second is the suggested `.xar` package, both for using on a Windows 8, 64 bit machine.

The first runs perfectly in "standalone" mode, but once the `hibernate.cfg.xml` file is changed to the preset MySQL Settings (which are accurate to my database), I get a very long `HTTP 500` error. (This is after I added the MySQL Connection Java file, and created a MySQL database according to the instructions on xwiki.org)  It seems that the primary issue is that it cannot find the `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` along with the fact that I get an error later on the page saying that it cannot create a database connection pool.

The code pertaining to the error is this:

```
<!-- DBCP Connection Pooling configuration
-->
<property name="dbcp.defaultAutoCommit">false</property>
<property name="dbcp.maxActive">50</property>
<property name="dbcp.maxIdle">5</property>
<property name="dbcp.maxWait">30000</property>
<property name="dbcp.whenExhaustedAction">1</property>
<property name="dbcp.ps.whenExhaustedAction">1</property>
<property name="dbcp.ps.maxWait">120000</property>
<property name="dbcp.ps.maxIdle">20</property>
<property name="connection.provider_class">com.xpn.xwiki.store.DBCPConnectionProvider</property>
```

and this

```
<!-- MySQL configuration.
Uncomment if you want to use MySQL and comment out other database configurations.
-->
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/xwiki</property>
<property name="connection.username">xwiki</property>
<property name="connection.password">xwiki</property>
<property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</property>
<property name="dbcp.ps.maxActive">20</property>
<mapping resource="xwiki.hbm.xml"/>
<mapping resource="feeds.hbm.xml"/>
<mapping resource="activitystream.hbm.xml"/>
<mapping resource="instance.hbm.xml"/>
```

And the error itself looks like this:

```
HTTP ERROR 500 

Problem accessing /xwiki/bin/view/Main/. Reason: 

Error number 3 in 0: Could not initialize main XWiki context 

Caused by: 

com.xpn.xwiki.XWikiException: Error number 3 in 0: Could not initialize main XWiki context 
at com.xpn.xwiki.XWiki.getMainXWiki(XWiki.java:422) 
at com.xpn.xwiki.XWiki.getXWiki(XWiki.java:491) 
at com.xpn.xwiki.web.XWikiAction.execute(XWikiAction.java:152) 
at com.xpn.xwiki.web.XWikiAction.execute(XWikiAction.java:128) 
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431) 
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236) 
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196) 
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414) 
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735) 
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:669) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1448) 
at com.xpn.xwiki.web.ActionFilter.doFilter(ActionFilter.java:121) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419) 
at org.xwiki.wysiwyg.server.filter.ConversionFilter.doFilter(ConversionFilter.java:144) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419) 
at com.xpn.xwiki.plugin.webdav.XWikiDavFilter.doFilter(XWikiDavFilter.java:66) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419) 
at org.xwiki.container.servlet.filters.internal.SavedRequestRestorerFilter.doFilter
(SavedRequestRestorerFilter.java:208) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419) 
at org.xwiki.container.servlet.filters.internal.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter
(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:111) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:455) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1075) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:384) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1009) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle
(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:368) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest
(AbstractHttpConnection.java:488) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete  
(AbstractHttpConnection.java:932) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete 
(AbstractHttpConnection.java:994) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:640) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:628) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) 
Caused by: com.xpn.xwiki.XWikiException: Error number 3202 in 3: Exception while reading  
document [xwiki:XWiki.XWikiServerClass] 
at com.xpn.xwiki.store.XWikiHibernateStore.loadXWikiDoc(XWikiHibernateStore.java:916) 
at com.xpn.xwiki.store.XWikiCacheStore.loadXWikiDoc(XWikiCacheStore.java:290) 
at com.xpn.xwiki.XWiki.getDocument(XWiki.java:1515) 
at com.xpn.xwiki.XWiki.getDocument(XWiki.java:1558) 
at com.xpn.xwiki.XWiki.initializeMandatoryClasses(XWiki.java:885) 
at com.xpn.xwiki.XWiki.initXWiki(XWiki.java:855) 
at com.xpn.xwiki.XWiki.<init>(XWiki.java:792) 
at com.xpn.xwiki.XWiki.getMainXWiki(XWiki.java:402) 
... 45 more 
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not create a DBCP pool. There is an error     
in the hibernate configuration file, please review it. 
at com.xpn.xwiki.store.DBCPConnectionProvider.configure(DBCPConnectionProvider.java:215) 
at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider
(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:143) 
at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider  
(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:84) 
at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.createConnectionProvider(SettingsFactory.java:459) 
at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:90) 
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2863) 
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2859) 
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1870) 
at com.xpn.xwiki.store.XWikiHibernateBaseStore.initHibernate(XWikiHibernateBaseStore.java:223) 
at com.xpn.xwiki.store.XWikiHibernateBaseStore.checkHibernate(XWikiHibernateBaseStore.java:640) 
at com.xpn.xwiki.store.XWikiHibernateStore.loadXWikiDoc(XWikiHibernateStore.java:789) 
... 52 more 
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver 
class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' 
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1429) 
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371) 
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044) 
at com.xpn.xwiki.store.DBCPConnectionProvider.configure(DBCPConnectionProvider.java:197) 
... 62 more 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver 
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) 
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) 
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) 
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) 
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:430) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:383) 
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1420) 
... 65 more 

Caused by: 

com.xpn.xwiki.XWikiException: Error number 3202 in 3: Exception while reading document   
[xwiki:XWiki.XWikiServerClass] 
at com.xpn.xwiki.store.XWikiHibernateStore.loadXWikiDoc(XWikiHibernateStore.java:916) 
at com.xpn.xwiki.store.XWikiCacheStore.loadXWikiDoc(XWikiCacheStore.java:290) 
at com.xpn.xwiki.XWiki.getDocument(XWiki.java:1515) 
at com.xpn.xwiki.XWiki.getDocument(XWiki.java:1558) 
at com.xpn.xwiki.XWiki.initializeMandatoryClasses(XWiki.java:885) 
at com.xpn.xwiki.XWiki.initXWiki(XWiki.java:855) 
at com.xpn.xwiki.XWiki.<init>(XWiki.java:792) 
at com.xpn.xwiki.XWiki.getMainXWiki(XWiki.java:402) 
at com.xpn.xwiki.XWiki.getXWiki(XWiki.java:491) 
at com.xpn.xwiki.web.XWikiAction.execute(XWikiAction.java:152) 
at com.xpn.xwiki.web.XWikiAction.execute(XWikiAction.java:128) 
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431) 
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236) 
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196) 
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414) 
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735) 
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:669) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1448) 
at com.xpn.xwiki.web.ActionFilter.doFilter(ActionFilter.java:121) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419) 
at org.xwiki.wysiwyg.server.filter.ConversionFilter.doFilter(ConversionFilter.java:144) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419) 
at com.xpn.xwiki.plugin.webdav.XWikiDavFilter.doFilter(XWikiDavFilter.java:66) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419) 
at org.xwiki.container.servlet.filters.internal.SavedRequestRestorerFilter.doFilter
(SavedRequestRestorerFilter.java:208) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419) 
at org.xwiki.container.servlet.filters.internal.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter
(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:111) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:455) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1075) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:384) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1009) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle
(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:368) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest
(AbstractHttpConnection.java:488) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete
(AbstractHttpConnection.java:932) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete
(AbstractHttpConnection.java:994) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:640) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:628) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) 
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not create a DBCP pool. There is an error     
in the hibernate configuration file, please review it. 
at com.xpn.xwiki.store.DBCPConnectionProvider.configure(DBCPConnectionProvider.java:215) 
at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider
(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:143) 
at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider  
(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:84) 
at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.createConnectionProvider(SettingsFactory.java:459) 
at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:90) 
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2863) 
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2859) 
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1870) 
at com.xpn.xwiki.store.XWikiHibernateBaseStore.initHibernate(XWikiHibernateBaseStore.java:223) 
at com.xpn.xwiki.store.XWikiHibernateBaseStore.checkHibernate
(XWikiHibernateBaseStore.java:640) 
at com.xpn.xwiki.store.XWikiHibernateStore.loadXWikiDoc(XWikiHibernateStore.java:789) 
... 52 more 
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver   
class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' 
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory   
(BasicDataSource.java:1429) 
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371) 
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044) 
at com.xpn.xwiki.store.DBCPConnectionProvider.configure(DBCPConnectionProvider.java:197) 
... 62 more 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver 
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) 
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) 
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) 
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) 
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:430) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:383) 
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory 
(BasicDataSource.java:1420) 
... 65 more
```

Do I have to use the `.xar` installation version to properly connect to a database? I tried that way also, with Xampp and Tomcat. Tomcat installed fine and I can easily access it through `localhost:(port)`. However, when I try to access my xwiki, I get a `HTTP 404` error saying that the reference cannot be found, which is odd since it shows up with the other files in the deployment list included in Tomcat, and the Tomcat example file shown there (located in the same Directory) works fine...

I'm a bit concerned that even if I could get the XWiki to work properly through Tomcat, I would still get the first error that I mentioned later when I try to connect the MySQL database.

*Side Note: I have suspicions that there may be Java file conflicts between those found in XWiki and those in Tomcat from other errors that I have seen while playing around and trying to make things work... but I could be wrong as I currently have very little knowledge of Java. I've seen several servlet errors and could not find class/file errors that according to a Forum that I found, are common errors belonging to the `jasper.jar` and the `jsp-api.jar`, both are found in Tomcat.*

Regardless, I am open to trying installation options that do or do not involve Tomcat. If anyone has had success with installing XWiki on Windows with a MySQL database, your help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score -6, accepted):

This was resolved some months ago. I was missing some vital information in the set-up, but it works fine now.

Comment: Hey, can you add in exactly how you solved it? For all the people who'll find this on Google in years to come? =)

Comment: Some info on how you solved it would be nice for those facing a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are missing the mysql driver. Since you converted the default distribution to use mysql, you will need to download a [mysql driver jar](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) and deploy it to your 'webapps\xwiki\WEB-INF\lib' directory.

Regarding the second issue, there is probably no connection between the database driver error, the xar and the tomcat 404. The xar is simply a collection of pages used to import or export content and functionality, but doesn't usually handle low level stuff like database conectivity. The 404 in Tomcat is probably due to the fact that you accessed a invalid url. Could need more details on that one.

Comment: Please see my comments below. :)

Answer (score 1):

First regarding potential conflict with Tomcat, I can assure you this is not possible as Tomcat is what XWiki team use in production all the time.

Now for MySQL, the error is pretty clear and if you really put the MySQL connector then you did not put it in the right place. What version of it did you put and is it in `#xwiki folder#/WEB-INF/lib/`?

The XAR package is not a different way of installing XWiki, it's a package containing wiki pages that can be imported in XWiki when it's running. Perhaps you mean the WAR package?

Comment: Hello and thank you for posting. I definitely do have the JAR Driver: mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.Jar, and I did mean the WAR file- sorry for the confusion. I also believe that Tomcat should be the way to go. I no longer have the Errors listed above, and my Xwiki is showing up in my Database and on my local Server like it should. I now have only 1 error, and it is the "Out of Memory" error that seems to be common with Java.

Comment: I believe that I am not running the Xwiki as a Service, but I have tried the Tomcat mini program as well as a way to Change the Memory allowance. Nothing is working...and I am just not sure where to look anymore. Is it possible that there is a preset somewhere in the code that I am inheriting?

Comment: I meant that the error is this: 
xwiki java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space, sorry I haven't looked at it for a few days.

Comment: I understand that the solution is to increase the Memory allowance, but I have tried all kinds of things like changing Catalina_Options and Java Options to numbers like: (1024, 1024, 512) and I still have the same error. The problem is that the number is not correctly being effected because in Tomcat Manager it is still 82. something, which is clearly not enough. I am not sure what "heap size" literally means. The error is coming from the PermGen, which I believe is listed as non-Ram Memory in Tomcat. My current set up is Xammp/Tomcat/Xwiki, and I really feel like I am only one step away...